# How to restart the VNC server?

Tags: vnc, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

How to restart the VNC server from command line? Without rebooting the machine, of course.

There's an annoying issue that VNC stops working after a Wi-Fi network is changed, so I hope restarting the VNC service will fix it, except I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Normally, a Service from that software should start. Since we don't know what type of VNC software you're using, consider using systemctl to look for and restart that service.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777:  `sudo systemctl list-jobs` shows "No jobs running". I'm running the default server, activated via `raspi-config`. Is there any reason to use a different one instead?

Comment: ` systemctl --type=service | grep vnc` shows nothing, but using `raspi-config` to re-enable VNC fixed it, I'm logged in via VNC right now. Could use the raspi-config CLI interface to do this.

Comment: Alright, I posted an answer to answer your original question.

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with VNC. If you change networks existing connections will cease.

Comment: @Milliways: I cannot reconnect via VNC after switching networks. But if I use `raspi-config` to enable VNC (even if it was already enabled), then I can (without rebooting).

Comment: If you want help you need to explain what "switching networks" actually means.

Comment: @Milliways: I just want an answer to the question, I don't expect the bug to be fixed as it doesn't affect many people. "Switching networks" means connecting to a different Wi-Fi network/SSID.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I apologize, I didn't fully research Bookworm and found that it uses WayVNC. I updated my answer accordingly to have instructions for WayVNC.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, It took a while, but I think I found the official ways to start WayVNC.

To stop WayVNC, type the command `wayvncctl wayvnc-exit`

To start WayVNC, type `wayvnc`

I hope this finally solves this issue

Sources:

https://github.com/any1/wayvnc/blob/master/wayvnc.scd&hl=en&gl=us (Found under section IPC commands)

https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/mo9389/problem_with_start_wayvnc/&hl=en&gl=us (I just used how they tried to start WayVNC)

Comment: `systemctl list-units | grep vnc` returns nothing

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Have you tried the command? Also, when you do systemctl stop vnc and press tab, does it show anything?

Comment: I have, of course, tried it - it says "Unit vncserver-x11-serviced.service not loaded". And pressing tab after "... vnc" does nothing. Does it work for you? Are you using Bookworm?

Comment: Still not quite there: `Failed to stop wayvnc.service: Unit wayvnc.service not found.` Just to clarify - I do have the stock Raspberry OS, I have installed a lot of stuff, but I have removed very little, and I definitely did not touch anything VNC-related.

Comment: Alright, hopefully this works. I updated my answer again.

Comment: Nice find! Almost, but here's the funny part: it refuses to start from SSH session because `WAYLAND_DISPLAY is not set in the environment`.

Comment: How can I run wayvnc in headless mode/over an SSH session?

Set the environment variables _WLR_BACKENDS_=headless and
_WLR_LIBINPUT_NO_DEVICES_=1 before starting the compositor, then run
wayvnc as normal.

Comment: That was found in the Github page listed on my answer: https://github.com/any1/wayvnc/blob/master/wayvnc.scd&hl=en&gl=us

Any other issue may be solvable on that GitHub repository